# Cronometro JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando crear un cronómetro en *JavaScript*, este funciona correctamente, pero necesito que sume los minutos a partir de 5, tengo un contador inicializado a 5 y otro que va controlando los minutos, pero necesito que establezca un *span* con minutos igual a 5 cuando el segundo contador sea igual al primero y a partir de ahí siga contando minutos...

Espero haberme explicado claramente. Adjunto mi código actual, ya que no consigo que sume los minutos a partir del 5 min.

**Contadores**

```
var contador_segundos = 0;
var contador_minutos = 0;
var contador = 5;
var cronometro;
var tiempoContratado;

function(){
    if(contador_segundos == 60){
        contador_segundos = 0;
        contador_minutos++;
        contador++;
        
        if(contador == contador_minutos){
            minutos.innerHTML = contador;
            minutos.innerHTML = contador_minutos;
        }

        
        if(contador_minutos == 60){
            contador_minutos = 0;
        }
    }

    segundos.innerHTML = contador_segundos;

    contador_segundos++;

},1000);
```

ACTUALIZACION

```
cronometro = setInterval(function (){
                    if(cronometro >= startMin){
                        sec++;
                        if(sec == 60){
                            min++;
                            sec = 0;
                            if(min == 60){
                                hour++;
                                min = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(sec);
                    minutos.innerHTML = min
                }, 1000);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira esto es lo que hice:

Lo primero directamente he llamado a una funcion anónima dandole un intervalo de 1 segundo, en ese segundo verifica que la variable inicial de cronometro es mayor o igual a la de los 5 minutos, si no es así incrementa hasta que se cumpla.
Una vez cumplida esta condición no es más que empezar a incrementar y contar mins, secs y horas aun este caso no lo pedías pero ahí lo llevas :-).
Espero que te sirva

```js
hasta5Min = document.getElementById("hasta5Min");
        despues5Min = document.getElementById("despues5Min");
        // Declaro variables para después de los 5 minutos.
        let sec= 0, min = 0, hour = 0;
        // Para contar hasta los 5 minutos
        let startMin = 5*60, cronometro = 0;
        // Creo la funcion
        setInterval(function (){
            if(cronometro >= startMin){
                sec++;
                if(sec == 60){
                    min++;
                    sec = 0;
                    if(min == 60){
                        hour++;
                        min = 0;
                    }
                }
                console.log(`Ha pasado 5 Min. Empezamos a contar: ${hour} Horas, ${min} Minutos y ${sec} Segundos.`);
                hasta5Min.style.display = 'none';
                despues5Min.innerHTML = `Ha pasado 5 Min. Empezamos a contar: ${hour} Horas, ${min} Minutos y ${sec} Segundos.`;
            }else{
                cronometro++
                console.log(`Tiempo restante a 5 Min ${startMin - cronometro} segundos`);
                hasta5Min.innerHTML = `Tiempo restante a 5 Min &rarr; ${startMin - cronometro} segundos`;
            }
        },1000);
```

```html
<div id="hasta5Min" style="color: red; font-weight: bolder;"></div>
<div id="despues5Min" style="color: green; font-weight: bolder;"></div>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no se aplicarla a mi código... Cuenta los segundos perfectamente, pero cuando llega a los 300s no sigue a contar a los minutos

Comment: Según tengo entendido por tu explicación lo que deseas es que a partir de los 5 minutos empiezas a contar, he leido tu corrección y la demo que te hice era para que vieses que a los 5 minutos te empezaba a contar. Creo que he entendido, quieres que a los 5 minutos te cuente ese tiempo pasado, no lo quieres cada segundo si no he entendido mal

Comment: quiero que cuente a partir de los 5 min, segundos y minutos. Ahí he adjuntado mi codigo, que cuenta los segundos, pero cuando llega a los 300s, quiero que siga por 6....7... pero solo minutos

Comment: he actualizado mi pregunta con mi código actual y con el innetHTML para los minutos

Answer (score 3):

El problema que veo es que estas aumentando las variables contador++ y contador_minutos++, por ende, nunca serán iguales :)

¿No estas usando interval?

Hice la prueba y me funciona bien tu código haciendo las modificaciones que te comenté

```
var contador_segundos = 0;
var contador_minutos = 0;
var contador = 5;
var cronometro;
var tiempoContratado;


function tiempo(){
    if(contador_segundos == 60){
        contador_segundos = 0;
        contador_minutos++;

        if(contador == contador_minutos){
            minutos.innerHTML = contador;
            minutos.innerHTML = contador_minutos;
            console.log("ok");
        }


        if(contador_minutos == 60){
            contador_minutos = 0;
        }
    }
    segundos.innerHTML = contador_segundos;
    contador_segundos++;
    console.log(contador_segundos);
};


setInterval(tiempo,1000);
```